# Can I protect certain page in PWA with a pin code?

Tags: vue.js, safari, progressive-web-apps

I'm building a PWA for a restaurant and I need to protect certain pages with a pincode or password.
Platform: Safari, iPads.

The app itself has only 2 views:

- show all tables
- show the bill of a specific table

When a waiter clicks a table it will show a bill that then will be handed over to the client. How can I restrict a client from going back to the main screen with all tables with a pin code or a password that will be set at the beginning of the work session, for example (when the waiter authenticates)?

Comment: Actually @soresu is perfectly correct. You can have the "isLocked" mode always set true by default, this will stop navigation if in locked mode. That value can be changed on pin validated by verifying it on an popup or similar. Once validated the waiter can navigate where he please until he lock it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a router middleware to prevent the client to navigate elsewhere.

```
router.beforeEach(function(to, from, next) {
    if (isLocked) {
        alert('Navigation is locked');
        next(false);
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

Here is an example where the waiter can lock the page after selecting the bill. Although it can be automatically set in mounted. You can adjust the code to your own needs.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Szgtafz/ngqkLtf6/)